# How to make at button to return to previous view X

Tags: xcode, ios6

I might be starring blind. Im trying to create a button that returns the previous view. But, the catch is, that I can navigate to this view, from three different views and I want to make sure I return to the correct one. Im not goint to use a navigation controller for this - I´d like my button to handle this transistion.[image]

I have illutstrated what Im trying to do. When I navigate to 'View1' from either view A, B or C, I want the same one button to be able to return me to the view I came from.

Is this possible?

Kind regards

The new-dev-guy

Comment: Instead of working "blind", why not learn about iOS before you try to program with it? You need to know the concepts at least. My chapter on view controllers would certainly have helped you here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html

Comment: I wouldt call this working blind. I just hit a wall here, and was not sure how to proceed. The learning curve for iOS development is steeper than I expected, and I appreciate the help Im getting from the community. The best way to learn - is doing, so I do have to code sometimes, without having the full understanding. I have read the chapter you linked to. Thanks. I´m going to read it again, there is a lot to comprehend.

Comment: Yes you *would* call it working blind. At least I thought you did. I was just repeating what *you* said. Look at your own question. *You* said "starring blind", whatever that meant. I was just trying to help. I wasn't making a judgment.

Comment: oh... I can see the confusion. What I meant by that, is when you stare at something and at the end can´t see what might be right in front of you. - language barrier :) Your input was great help. And have been reading your chapter on view, and need to read it a couple more times i think. Much to grasp in one go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other way which I preferred is to use the `UINavigationController`. From the above diagram  what I can understand is the from **view A**, **view B**, **View C** you can navigate to the **View 1** and then when you want to go back just click or tap on back button will take you the the previous controller.
For that just use the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` for navigate to the previous view controller with animation an replace NO instead of YES to navigate to the previous view without animation.
And for navigate to the **View 1** use the `[self.navigationController pushViewController:View 1 animated:YES];` for animated navigation and for non-animated transition use NO.

Comment: It is my placer that I can helpful to you and my code solve you problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do it like this, but if you absolutely have to, then do this: Assuming you have all the 4 views and the back button in a single controller, create a UIVIew property called "**previousView**" in your controller, and just before animating View1 from either  View A, B or C, just set **self.previousView = viewA** (or B or C), now on pressing the back button, you'll know which view to go back to from the saved previousView property.